# Making a sub in Master Page page-specific

Tags: vb.net, master-pages

in my master page init sub I have a block of data/text being written to a control. The basic idea was that it should be available on every page (obviously). However, I have come across a situation in which I need this to NOT happen on a certain page. Is there anything I can do, short of making a new master page for this specific page, to make this work? I also use a basepage, if that ever needs to come into play. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a virtual readonly property in your base page class called `ShouldDoThingy` that always returns false.

Override it in this specific page to return true.

In the master page, check `if (((BasePageClass)Page).ShouldDoThingy)`

Comment: you lost me a bit on that if statement

Comment: @goose: The `if` statement checks the property value of the current `Page`.  It needs to cast `Page` to your base type.

Answer (score 0):

If it is only a page or two and you don't have a basepage class you can use as suggested by SLaks, you can always just check the current request url:

```
            If Context.Request.PathInfo.ToLower.Contains("/pagename.aspx") = True Then
            'do something
        End If
```